# How to check amazon Linux version on Lambda@Edge?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Below content is reference from [recent Amazon notification](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-updates-to-the-aws-lambda-execution-environment/)

*We are updating the AWS Lambda and AWS Lambda@Edge execution environment to include recent versions of Amazon Linux and software packages.*

How can I know, what Linux version currently Amazon having? Or where can I see it?